# combine two rdd in pyspaek

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I have two rdd in pyspark

```
rdd1=sc.parallelize(['a','b'])
rdd2=sc.parallelize(['c','d'])
```

I want to generate a rdd with pairs which conclude one element of each rdd. [(a,c),(b,c),(a,d),(b,d)]
I tried

```
rdd3=rdd1.map(lambda x:x)+rdd2.map(lambda y:y)
```

it failed

Comment: what is your expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for cartesian product:

```
rdd1.cartesian(rdd2)
```